# In Nginx, I want to redirect the sub-domain request with request-uri to sub-domain but if there is no request-uri in it should redirect to main domain

Tags: nginx, subdomain

My problem statement : 
my domain : example.com 
sub-domain : main.example.com

when we will access: 
1. http://main.example.com/xyz or https://main.example.com/xyz : 
It must be redirect to https://main.example.com/xyz

2. http://main.example.com or https://main.example.com : 
   It must be redirect to https://www.example.com

I am using nginx. What will be configuration file for Nginx server?

My current setting is :

```
server{
        listen 443;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /var/www/html/demo.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /var/www/html/demo.key;
        server_name main.example.com$request_uri;

       location / {
                root /var/www/html;
                index  index.html index.htm;
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name main.example.com$request_uri;
    return 301 https://main.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name main.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
}

server {
    listen 443;
    server_name main.example.com;
    return 301 https://www.example.com;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
server{
    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name          main.example.com;
    ssl_certificate      /var/www/html/demo.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key  /var/www/html/demo.key;

    location / {
        proxy_pass https://www.example.com;
    }

    location ~ ^(/.+) {
         return 301  https://main.example.com$1;
    }
}
```

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#single_http_https_server

Comment: with this setting https://main.example.com/xyz  is redirecting to  https://main.example.com/xyz (this is perfect) while https://main.example.com is redirecting to https://main.example.com which is wrong it has to redirect https://www.example.com.

Comment: Did you use `http://main.example.com` or `https://main.example.com` ? Both are redirecting to `https://main.example.com` ? Technically it shouldn't. Please note I haven't tested it.

Comment: Made minor change to the second location block in my answer as nginx is thinking main.example.com in proxy_pass is an upstream server. I just tested it on my nginx (nginx version: nginx/1.12.2) and it's working as expected i.e `http(s)://main.example.com` is redirecting to `https://www.example.com`. Maybe try clearing your cache and see if it's working. Also stop and start nginx after changes instead of reload

Comment: does last block expression will change for  `http://main.example.com/abcd?ZGVtb0lkPTM0MzIzNA==` for this link?

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by expression will change ? Like redirect you mean ?

Comment: I mean to say about  regex expression

Comment: will this `~ ^(/.+) ` expression will work for this request_uri  `/abcd?ZGVtb0lkPTM0MzIzNA==`?